# How do I construct a linked list using a vector of vectors created by a for loop?

Tags: c++, loops, pointers, linked-list

I am trying to add pointers to a 2D matrix I just created using a vector of vectors. The code I want to use does it with arrays, but I would like to instead use the vector of vectors I just created. So my questions are:

1. Is this possible?
2. If so, what do I need to change in the code I want to use?

Below is my code for creating the vector of vectors. K is the number of rooms which the vectors are representing and has been previously initialized.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < K; ++i) //a loop for each room
    {
        int M = 0; // initializing rows variable
        int N = 0; // initializing columns variable
        cin >> M >> N;

        vector<vector<int> > matrix(M); //give a matrix with a dimension M*N with all elements set to 0
        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++)
            matrix[i].resize(N);

        for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) //adding each row to the matrix
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++) //adding each column to the matrix
            {
                cin >> matrix[i][j]; //putting all the elements in the matrix
            }
        }

    }
```

Here is the code I would like to use, if possible:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/construct-linked-list-2d-matrix/

I'm pretty new at C++, so my apologies if this is a ridiculous question.

Comment: the question is not really clear. Is the code not doing what you want?

Comment: The code displayed above seems to work fine, but what I want to do is use this to create a linked list as they did in the webpage I linked below the code

Comment: there is not much you have to change, actually only changing the signature of the methods should get you almost there. The only thing of the 2d array that is used in the code you link is accessing elements via `[i][j]`  and you can do the same with a vector of vectors. What did you try? What specific problems did you encounter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it if you replace the prototype:

```
Node* construct(int arr[][3], int i, int j,  
                              int m, int n)
{
    //...
}
```

By:

```
Node* construct(const vector<vector<int>> & arr, int i, int j,  
                                                 int m, int n)
{
    //...
}
```

This way, it should work since you can access vectors elements with `operator[]`.

I hope it can solve your problem.

---

**EDIT:**

To avoid warnings, you could even write:

```
Node* construct(const vector<vector<int>> & arr, size_t i, size_t j,  
                                                 size_t m, size_t n)
{
    //...
}
```

---

**EDIT2: Full example code**

I used exactly the code you gave us in your question:

```
// CPP program to construct a linked list
// from given 2D matrix
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// struct node of linked list
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* right, *down;
};

// returns head pointer of linked list
// constructed from 2D matrix
Node* construct(const vector<vector<int>> & arr, size_t i, size_t j,
                                                 size_t m, size_t n)
{
    // return if i or j is out of bounds
    if (i > n - 1 || j > m - 1)
        return nullptr;

    // create a new node for current i and j
    // and recursively allocate its down and
    // right pointers
    Node* temp = new Node();
    temp->data = arr[i][j];
    temp->right = construct(arr, i, j + 1, m, n);
    temp->down  = construct(arr, i + 1, j, m, n);
    return temp;
}

// utility function for displaying
// linked list data
void display(Node* head)
{
    // pointer to move right
    Node* Rp;

    // pointer to move down
    Node* Dp = head;

    // loop till node->down is not NULL
    while (Dp) {
        Rp = Dp;

        // loop till node->right is not NULL
        while (Rp) {
            cout << Rp->data << " ";
            Rp = Rp->right;
        }
        cout << "\n";
        Dp = Dp->down;
    }
}

// driver program
int main()
{
    // 2D matrix
    vector<vector<int>> arr = { {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9} };

    size_t m = 3, n = 3;
    Node* head = construct(arr, 0, 0, m, n);
    display(head);
    return 0;
}
```

I replaced your code by a more efficient and readable vector initialization.

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Oh cool, thanks. One last question then: I'm having trouble figuring out where to put this in my code that I posted above... I tried something but it resulted in "local function definitions are illegal" which I'm guessing is a result of my placement in the for loop above. Do you have an idea of how to integrate this into my previous code?

Comment: Your code above is the matrix creation (put it in the `main()` for example, where you want). The prototype I suggested to you is the one provided in the link you gave us in your question, go check, you will see the `construct()` function. This is this function whose the prototype needs to be replaced by the one I gave to you.

Comment: I will put an edit with the full example code if you are still in trouble to understand :)

Comment: Ahh thanks for doing that, but I actually need to set up my vector of vectors in this way because it is reading items from a text file. I am not supposed to know what is exactly on the file except for the general format. But I need to read the items and put them in matrices that represent maps of rooms. And then I was trying to create a linked list of those matrices so that each node has a pointer to its neighbor. If that makes sense... I will try to play around with this a bit more to see if it can work. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @ashe_lam Yes, you can keep you way of building the vector, it will work the same :) I just used the initializer list to write a readable example. You are welcome !

Comment: Ok great, I think I got it. Unfortunately, when I run my code using the terminal I get a "Debug Assertion Failed!" popup where it says the vector subscript is out of range. I think I will post this in a new question though because I might need to post my new code for clarification.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193402/discussion-between-ashe-lam-and-fareanor).